# Call operator() of underlying obejct pointed by std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++

I have this class with operator() defined:

```
class Base{
...
public:
int operator()(int arg)
{
  return arg+42;
}
virtual void run(void) = 0;
...
};
```

some derived class:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
...
public:
  void run(void)
  {
    //do something
  }
};
```

and then there is this data structure

```
struct Routine
{
    const uint16_t routine_id;
    std::unique_ptr<Base> callback;
};

const Routine routines[] = {
    { 0x0001, std::make_unique<Derived>() },
    { 0x0002, std::make_unique<Derived2>() }
    // etc
};
```

is there better syntax for calling operator() through p than this:

```
std::cout << routines[0].callback->operator()(21);
```

?

Comment: `std::cout << (*routines[0].callback)(21);` ?

Answer (score 5):

> is there better syntax for calling operator() through p than this:
>
> ```
> std::cout << routines[0].callback->operator()(21);
> ```
>
> ?

You can dereference the pointer:

```
std::cout << (*routines[0].callback)(21);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to add a operator() to your routine struct:

```
struct Routine
{
    const uint16_t routine_id;
    std::unique_ptr<Base> callback;
    int operator()(int arg) const
    {
       return callback->operator()(arg);
    }
};
```

so that you can write directly

```
std::cout << routines[0](21);
```

which is more or less what your code means here.